# Add javascript to Discussion Board Topic page

Tags: javascript, 2013

I'd like to add javascript to discussion board topic pages. Thatis, the page that consists of a single Topic, and lists all the replies to that topic.

From google, I've learnt that I can add a ScriptEditor webpart, however in the list tab on the page I'd like to edit, under Form Web Parts, it just lists the forms for new, display, or edit a topic, not the current page itself. How can I add javascript to the page I want?

Thanks

Comment: You mean that there are no other categories than Form Webparts to choose from?

Comment: Not in the ribbon bar there wasn't, but I've noticed it in the settings icon. Problem solved (ill mark it answer tomorrow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking in the wrong place. Instead of being in the ribbon bar, it's in the settings icon in the right -> "Edit Page". This seems to do what I want.